# Deploy Contract Syntax Error

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

I am testing a contract, when I run the `truffle migrate` command, in my deplyment contract located in the migrations folder the following error appears:

```
var HelloWorld=artifacts.require (“./HelloWorld.sol”);
                                  ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I am using solidty 0.5.0, What is wrong with the syntax of the `.js` file.

Comment: You have to use the symbol `"` (Unicode Quotation Mark U+0022) to delimit strings in javascript. Others symbols like `“` (Left Double Quotation Mark U+201C) nor `”` (Right Double Quotation Mark U+201D) are not accepted (yet). It is common in some pages to replace `"` by the later symbols because they look nicer on screen, but unfortunately that will not work for source code and it will break copy+paste examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using invalid quotation marks. You have to use `"`...